# hook_module_preuninstall doesn't run early enough

Tags: 8, installation

Uninstalling my module threw this error:

[error]  my_module: The My Field field type is used in the following field: my_module.my_field

But, since my module defines both an entity and a field, both of which will be uninstalled when I uninstall this module, it doesn't make sense.  I'm trying to handle this by removing all of the fields programmatically in hook_module_preuninstall, which I have in the .module file because it wasn't working in the .install file.

The problem is, this hook runs *after* the checks for field dependencies.  It would make more sense if it ran before, in my opinion, but, what can I use to get ahead of these checks?  Anything?  If not, what should I do so that my module realizes it needs to uninstall these things when the module is uninstalled?

Also, shouldn't this hook run earlier?  If not, what is the point of it?

Comment: You could also decorate the **module_installer** service and override the `::uninstall()` method. Execute your code prior to the `parent::uninstall($module_list, $uninstall_dependents)` call. I used this method to overcome a similar problem.
See https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/decorated-services-drupal-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is currently no hook to do this.

The only thing you can do is have your own custom uninstall form that allows you to prepare the uninstall by deleting all data and then delete the field through the API, then point the user to the uninstall form.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Don't you think there should be?  Is there any use for hook_module_preuninstall the way it is?

Comment: Yes, that hook is really not very useful, it was added before config dependencies were. I suggest you look for or create an issue and a patch, should not be too hard to the hook up. The challenge I guess is what if your preuninstall hook runs, you delete something, and then there is still a validation problem? Then your module might be in a broken state (the same is true for my approach, though)

Comment: It looks like, if I'm reading it right, this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2350111 will create an onModuleUninstall event which I can subscribe to, which will hopefully happen before the config dependencies are checked?

Comment: And, if I were to make a patch, which Drupal version should I use? 8.3.7? 8.4.x? 8.5.x?

Comment: Don't worry about that, that's usually easy to change and is for the release manager to decide. Depends on whether it is classified as a bugfix, feature or something inbetween.